# _.indexOf not finding the value of my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

```
       <div class="login-info-panel">        
         <ul>
         <li class="home">Home</li>
         <li class="info">info</li>
        </ul>
       </div>       


            var myli = $('.login-info-panel > ul >li');
    var infoButton = $('li.info');
    console.log(_.indexOf(myli, infoButton));
```

using underscore.js you would assume that li.info  is in the array and it would shoot back a value of 1 (the index). but instead I am getting -1 (which means its not found in my array.

am I missing something obvious?

here is a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Zuriel/UVqGH/

Comment: Infobutton itself is a DomElement Set (Array) where you would have to reference the first element. So `_.indexOf(myli, infoButton[0])` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple use:

```
var myli = $('.login-info-panel > ul >li');
var infoButton = $('li.info');
console.log(_.indexOf(myli, infoButton[0])); // 1
```

I think the desired behaviour is:

```
myli.filter(infoButton); // [jQuery Object]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not mix jquery and underscore in that way.

```
var myli = $('.login-info-panel > ul >li');
var index = myli.index('li.info');
```

Comment: What should I not mix?  the way I have my syntax?

Comment: @ZurielAndrusyshyn jquery objects already have a lot of the functionality that you should use instead.

Comment: well I was under the impression that underscore uses the native indexOf for modern browsers but a shim for ie7 and 8  so thats why I have underscore in the mix.

Comment: @ZurielAndrusyshyn absolutely - but jquery does this for you.